# How to check if number greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, int

In ECMAScript, the maximal value of `number` is `9007199254740991`. But how to check is value greater than `9007199254740991`?

```
// ---------------- ↓ We don't know at advance which value user will pass
function examle(parameter: number | BigInt): void {
    // check the value before do something with it
}
```

Below code works as expected, but I not sure that do it right.

```
console.log(9007199254740992 > 9007199254740991); // "true"
console.log(9007199254740993 > 9007199254740991); // "true"
console.log(9007199254740994 > 9007199254740991); // "true"
```

Comment: Why not just use `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: You mean `parameter > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` check when we don't know parameter value at advance?

Comment: I don't see why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript all numbers (integers and reals) are stored using double-precision floating-point numbers. The actual maximum is `Number.MAX_VALUE` which is somewhere around `1.79E+308`. So you are doing everything right.

See [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), [MAX_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) and [this article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Also try writing to console numbers bigger than 9007199254740991. You'll see that they are not as precise

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's userful.